# How to determine the precision, recall and f-measure of my binary segmentation task?

Tags: python, classification

I've trained a model that tries to segment objects of interest in an image. I want evaluate the performance of my model by determining the precision, recall and f-measure of the network output.

I know that `precision=tp/(tp+fp)` and `recall=tp/(tp+fn)`. I found out that `sklearn.metrics` has multiple functions to determine these values but I cant seem to effectively use these functions.

At first I had written a script that found the `tp`, `fp` and `fn` values and returned the actual `int` numbers so for example in one sample I have 2 objects of interest in the ground truth but the network detected 4 objects of interest so these put my values at:

`tp = 2, fp = 2 and fn = 0`

Now I cant use these as `sklearn.metrics` expects arrays as inputs, so I rewrote my script to give the following arrays:

```
gt_array = [1, 1]
pred_array = [1, 0, 1, 0]
```

as two of the predictions were correct while the other two were misclassified objects.

If I give this to the function:

```
metrics.classification_report(gt_array, pred_array)
```

and

```
metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support(gt_array, pred_array,average='binary')
```

I get the error:

```
{ValueError}Multi-label binary indicator input with different numbers of labels
```

which I can see, but I assumed the function will automatically, from the size differences, determine the `fn` and `fp` values.

So how do I determine these metrics when I have varying sizes of arrays. In some samples the `ground_truth` has 10 detections but the network output only shows `5`, so in this case how do I incorporate the `fn` values in the above function?

Thanks

Comment: Well, how about you assign `1` to every object of your pool that is interesting and `0` otherwise. Than you will have `y_true` and `y_pred` at the same length and you can proceed with sklearn functions

Comment: Theyre different lengths because of the false positives and false negatives. If the ground truth says that there are two objects resent in this sample and the network detects 4, 2 of which are false positives then. This would cause the arrays of different length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you've failed to define your metric for correct operation.  Think of each index for a list as the ID# for an object of interest -- "interest" being flagged by *either* the ground truth or the model.  Each list must cover *all* of the objects.

For your case, you have four objects; let's let the real ones be items 0 and 1.  Your lists should look like this:

```
gt_array   = [1, 1, 0, 0]    # First two items are of interest; not the others.
pred_array = [1, 1, 1, 1]    # All four items are of interest.
```

This isn't just a matter of zero-filling the `gt` list to the length of the `pred`; you also need to match the identified objects.  For instance, consider an image with only two items of interest: a cat and a dog.  The prediction model identifies four items: dog, sky, wall, grass.  Now, you have *five* objects tagged, but only one is correct:

```
#            cat dog sky wall grass
gt_array   = [1,  1,  0,  0,    0]    # First two items are of interest
pred_array = [0,  1,  1,  1,    1]    # one FN, three FP, one TP
```

One other thing to note in your process is that you are not incorporating true negatives.  If you plan to compute anything requiring the fourth category, you'll have to define a good way to measure the the natural filter (that spot is booooooorinnngg!).  I suggest that you ignore it: trying to measure the quality of ignoring things is a slippery slope.

---

**classification_report** takes two arguments: ground truth and predictions.  You appear to misunderstand the prediction vector.  Your predictor said "interesting" for all four objects, so that vector is all `1`s.  The ground truth is [1, 1, 0, 0] (in my ordering) because only the first two are truly interesting.

You're trying to make the comparison yourself.  That's not your job; that's part of what `classification_report` does for you.  Your model predicted for objects, so you have four `1` entries in your prediction list.

Comment: Thank you for answering. So in my case where ``gt`` shows 2 objects and ``pred`` shows 4 objects. Then my ``gt`` would be ``[1,1,0,0]`` and ``pred`` would be ``[1,0,1,0]``. But what of in case where network fails to detect all of the objects and in such ``gt`` array would be larger than ``pred``. I'm not considering true negatives at all as they are not counted in the ``precision`` and recall`` equations. So I dont have to worry about that.

Comment: Why would `pred` be `[1, 0, 1, 0]`?

Comment: My answer includes the case where `pred` fails to identify all objects; that's why the "cat" slot is `0`.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, I'm using a distance measure to determine differentiate between ``tp`` and ``fp``. so pred would be ``[1,0,1,0]`` because the first and third index are ``tp`` while the second and fourth are ``fp``

Comment: Or if I understand correctly, in my case my ``pred`` should be ``[1,1,0,0]`` as both ground truth have been correctly identified along with two other objects that are ``fp``

Comment: That's not how [classification_report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) works.

Comment: Hence my question here. The reason I asked is because I dont really understand the implementation and use of the function

Comment: Good; does my addition to the answer explain it well enough for you to move forward?  Does the documentation help?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but I see no other way than making the comparison myself as I have to provide the two arrays ``y_true`` and ``y_pred``. You mentioned, ``Think of each index for a list as the ID# for an object of interest -- "interest" being flagged by either the ground truth or the model. Each list must cover all of the objects.`` and from the cat, dog example I understood that ``[1,1,0,0]`` there are 4 objects but 2 are objects of interest. and my model has detected 2 along with two more. So am I not supposed to write the ``y_pred`` array myself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189148/discussion-between-prune-and-stuckinphd).